# How do I use Scalene to profile my Pytest test suit?

Tags: python, pytest, profiler, scalene

I want to use Scalene to profile my Pytest test suit

Typically I run the test suit by running

```
pytest
```

So I tried

```
scalene pytest
```

which doesn't work as I expect.

What is the correct way to run my test suit through scalene?

Answer (score 7):

Since Scalene replaces your python interpreter, you have to run pytest as a module from Scalene, like so:

```
scalene -m pytest
```

which yields the desired result